# Replace a Relationship-Node->Relationship construct with one Realtionship containing the label of the replaced node

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have a graph where if have the following constructs:

```
(a)-[b:Input]->(c:Data)-[e:Output]->(f)
```

i want to replace b,c,e with a relationship with the label from c:

```
(a)-[n:Data]->(f)
```

The label should be generated automatically. I have multiple labels for c like: Data, AMC, Door, New_HS etc..
So the label of the new created relationship should be created like this:

```
[n:title = c.Label]
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? Do you have an error you want to show/explain to us?

Comment: I tried `match (a)-[o:FOLLOWS]->(b)-[l:REVIEWED]->(c) create (a)-[r:b.name]->(c)` -> Error: Invalid input '.': expected
and
`match (a)-[o:FOLLOWS]->(b)-[l:REVIEWED]->(c) create (a)-[r:title =b.name]->(c)` -> Error: Invalid input '=': expected

Comment: Thanks for your reply felix, the question is clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

We cannot create a relationship based on a property. You need to create a new relationship and change the type (or relationship name) to your data label name. I used an apoc function to change (or update) that. What I did is

> 1. Find all nodes and relationship that are attached to Data
> 2. Create the needed relationship but use a dummy relationship type:  REL
> 3. Use apoc function apoc.refactor.setType to change the relationship type from REL to c.label
> 4. Don't forget to remove the dummy relationship REL

```
Match (a)-[:Input]->(c:Data)-[:Output]->(f)
CREATE (a)-[r:REL]->(f) 
WITH a, r, c, f
CALL apoc.refactor.setType(r, c.label)
YIELD input, output
WITH a, c, f 
MATCH (a)-[rel:REL]->(f) 
DELETE rel
RETURN a,  f
```

BEFORE:
[image]

AFTER:

[image]